# Dell XPS 15 in that the wi-fi would drop out every 20 mins

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dell-xps

I'm having serious issues with my Dell XPS 15 in that the wi-fi would drop out every 20 mins or so at home. It has been widely reported that the XPS 15 (L521x) has had wireless problems.

I have googled and `reset/flushdns` and also `netsh int ip reset` but restart couple of times but nothing seem to be working for me.

Can anybody guide me what exactly do I need to fix this issue? my warrenty is expired.

Check this site too.
http://help.aol.com/help/microsites/microsite.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=223839

Comment: Have you contacted the Dell people for a little advise?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of search finally I found Intel driver and I have installed and seems stable for now and this will help others avoiding frustration and wasting hours of your time... enjoy

[Intel Driver PROSet/Wireless Software](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24217&lang=eng&ProdId=3502)